# Copy and Paste a Specific Cell Range within a Column with a Dynamic Last Row VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and past every other cell within Column A of one of my sheets starting with A1 and paste it to the next cell for 2k+ rows in the same sheet. Will be using for new data set each time though so I'm not sure how to make the end of the range dynamic.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll find many examples here.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()
'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba